# Parent child relationships in Loopback

Tags: foreign-key-relationship, loopbackjs, loopback

I have two loopback models, say `Product` and `Service`. They are related to a parent model `Asset`. The `Asset` has an `AssetType` which says if the current object is a `Product` or a `Service`. How do I model the entity relationships for this case?

Comment: Please: Find a reference to a particular ER modeling method & tell us what it is. Give and justify as much of a design that you can come up with that you think would be mapped to your models according to the loopback documentation. Then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use polymorphic relations
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Polymorphic-relations.html

```
"parent": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "polymorphic": {
        "foreignKey": "parentId",
        "discriminator": "parentType"
    }
}
```